# Open sets in Minkowski spacetime

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, topology, metric-space

I don't know how to imagine open sets in Minkowski spacetime. I have seen that there are many diffrent ways of constructing them — that's OK. But for example. which construction do people mean in the case of the [Reeh-Schlieder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reeh%E2%80%93Schlieder_theorem)?

In such an example, do I have to imagine balls in 4-dimensional Euclidean spacetime (simply treating time as additional axis) and forget about lightcones and stuff?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Choice of metric/topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ when we say a manifold is locally homeomorphic to it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/562571/2451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topologically, Minkowski spacetime is $\mathbb{R}^4$, and most (all?) spacetimes you'll ever see are products of common spaces like Euclidean spaces, spheres, tori, etc. The metric is irrelevant; strictly speaking, the topology comes before.

So yes, one possible basis is the set of open balls of Euclidean space.